# Remove extra space around path of SVG

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I currently have an svg I have converted to a react component using the very helpful tool svgr https://react-svgr.com/.  The issue I am noticing is that there is all this extra white space around the path of my svg.  I am wondering if it is possible to remove this extra spacing. My code is as follows:

```
import * as React from "react";

function SvgComponent(props) {
  return (
    <svg
      preserveAspectRatio="none"
      style={{ border: "solid 1px red" }}
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width={400}
      height={108.439}
      viewBox="0 0 400 108.439"
      {...props}
    >
      <g fillRule="evenodd">
        <path
          d="M134.833 56.833V58h239.5v-2.333h-239.5v1.166m41.413 25.542c-.204.551-2.284 6.906-2.332 7.125-.03.138-.07.25-.089.25-.019 0-.053.15-.077.333-.091.715-.789 2.26-1.094 2.424-.846.452-.388.826 1.013.826 1.222 0 1.333-.027 1.333-.333 0-.183-.104-.333-.232-.333-.748 0-.991-.554-.698-1.594.567-2.018.449-1.906 2.014-1.906h1.377l.436 1.399c.539 1.729.541 1.901.02 2.032-1.174.295-.472.735 1.172.735 1.775 0 2.054-.174 1.373-.856-.274-.275-.891-1.887-2.047-5.352-1.549-4.64-1.914-5.439-2.169-4.75m31.504.069c-2.983 1.572-3.68 7.26-1.2 9.802 3.71 3.803 8.543-1.556 6.534-7.246-.823-2.334-3.407-3.572-5.334-2.556m55.581.033c-1.862.995-1.733 3.599.261 5.286 2.802 2.371 3.226 3.271 2.143 4.558-1.059 1.258-2.34.455-2.906-1.821-.482-1.944-.829-1.601-.829.821 0 1.901.018 2.012.333 2.012.186 0 .334-.111.334-.25 0-.314-.014-.315.856.08 2.548 1.156 4.631-.762 4.071-3.748-.128-.681-1.549-2.216-2.491-2.691-2.14-1.079-2.391-3.891-.347-3.891.867 0 1.744 1.18 1.744 2.345 0 .378.076.489.333.489.301 0 .334-.111.334-1.146 0-.63.047-1.38.104-1.667.114-.569-.461-.8-.666-.268-.083.218-.182.207-.723-.083-.784-.42-1.795-.43-2.551-.026m17.75-.183c-.155.112-1.653 4.404-1.673 4.789-.032.66-1.683 5.033-2.015 5.341-.758.703-.544.909.94.909 1.403 0 1.987-.466.92-.734-.525-.132-.658-.644-.418-1.604.103-.41.241-.97.307-1.245l.121-.5 1.415-.048 1.416-.047.453 1.391c.559 1.716.563 1.92.036 2.052-1.173.295-.471.735 1.172.735 1.785 0 2.109-.205 1.388-.879-.288-.269-.855-1.735-2.062-5.329-.915-2.727-1.702-4.957-1.748-4.955-.046.001-.159.057-.252.124m38.033-.002c-.098.169-1.797 5.363-1.863 5.694-.239 1.206-1.345 4.117-1.683 4.431-.767.71-.557.916.932.916 1.222 0 1.333-.027 1.333-.333 0-.215-.111-.333-.313-.333-.743 0-.872-1.157-.307-2.75l.236-.667 1.406-.048 1.406-.047.453 1.391c.559 1.716.562 1.92.036 2.052-1.174.295-.471.735 1.172.735 1.798 0 2.148-.226 1.376-.891-.324-.278-.765-1.406-1.964-5.025-1.805-5.446-1.903-5.673-2.22-5.125m-135.447 1.791c0 1.596.027 1.75.31 1.75.246 0 .329-.165.405-.799.175-1.48.663-2.034 1.793-2.034h.492v4.5c0 4.889-.054 5.167-1 5.167-.223 0-.334.111-.334.333 0 .315.111.333 2 .333s2-.018 2-.333c0-.218-.111-.333-.321-.333-.811 0-.845-.207-.845-5.096V83h.566c.812 0 1.31.582 1.522 1.779.322 1.821.745 1.433.745-.683v-1.763h-7.333v1.75m10.5 0c0 1.639.021 1.75.333 1.75.246 0 .333-.111.333-.426 0-1.488.619-2.407 1.621-2.407H197l-.003 4.542c-.002 4.847-.006 4.87-.715 5.048-.308.077-.448.209-.413.388.089.468 3.964.494 3.964.027 0-.227-.109-.338-.333-.338-.946 0-1-.278-1-5.167V83h.489c1.183 0 1.591.448 1.821 2 .223 1.506.601.952.654-.958l.048-1.709H194.167v1.75m23.5-1.432c0 .236.106.349.327.349.603 0 .673.505.673 4.894 0 4.452-.051 4.773-.762 4.773-.131 0-.238.152-.238.339 0 .464 3.375.439 3.464-.025.035-.183-.105-.301-.435-.367-.619-.124-.691-.398-.694-2.656L220 88.167h.738c.929 0 1.331.455 1.595 1.801.631 3.23.753 3.449 1.922 3.449.915 0 1.773-.731 1.394-1.188-.17-.205-.235-.202-.478.017-.605.548-.626.514-1.177-1.872-.272-1.179-.466-1.653-.821-2.008l-.464-.465.541-.355c1.612-1.056 1.581-3.731-.053-4.748-.922-.573-5.53-.695-5.53-.147m11.166.016c0 .21.111.333.3.333.665 0 .7.238.7 4.758 0 4.595-.052 4.909-.817 4.909-.114 0-.182.131-.151.291.048.249.252.292 1.385.292s1.337-.043 1.385-.292c.038-.199-.049-.291-.278-.291-.81 0-.857-.246-.856-4.471.001-3.376.033-3.886.222-3.529.122.229.675 1.204 1.229 2.166.554.963 1.418 2.538 1.919 3.5 2.195 4.216 2.128 4.269 2.131-1.696.003-5.338.016-5.449.686-5.583.327-.065.479-.197.479-.415 0-.293-.117-.315-1.459-.27-1.566.051-2.019.381-.916.667l.541.14-.003 3.287-.003 3.287-.508-.917c-.28-.504-1.001-1.854-1.602-3a112.838 112.838 0 00-1.504-2.791l-.411-.709h-1.235c-1.123 0-1.234.03-1.234.334M241 82.655c0 .207.134.341.375.375l.375.053v9.334l-.375.164c-.206.091-.375.298-.375.462 0 .277.231.294 3.375.252l3.375-.045.048-1.625c.044-1.502.023-1.625-.269-1.625-.25 0-.339.161-.421.757-.188 1.377-.825 1.91-2.28 1.91-1.295 0-1.328-.062-1.328-2.506V88h.474c.617 0 .983.423 1.123 1.296.086.537.186.704.424.704.29 0 .312-.162.312-2.25 0-2.115-.019-2.25-.323-2.25-.255 0-.347.158-.436.755-.121.807-.41 1.078-1.146 1.078h-.428v-2.065c0-2.354-.056-2.268 1.477-2.268 1.27 0 1.618.267 1.859 1.428.314 1.516.703 1.195.77-.636l.053-1.459h-3.33c-3.178 0-3.329.015-3.329.322m9.833-.048c0 .15.11.356.245.458.135.102.885 1.551 1.667 3.221l1.422 3.036v3.04l-.5.189c-1.198.452-.639.798 1.206.746 1.742-.048 2.495-.418 1.407-.691-.756-.19-.901-3.208-.221-4.57.217-.432.445-.999.508-1.26.192-.8 1.602-3.621 1.858-3.719.832-.319.222-.724-1.092-.724-1.222 0-1.333.028-1.333.334 0 .215.111.333.313.333.504 0 .719.403.595 1.112-.101.581-1.319 3.639-1.562 3.924-.099.116-2.096-4.284-2.096-4.617 0-.091.206-.263.458-.384.977-.468.576-.702-1.208-.702-1.434 0-1.667.039-1.667.274m37.536 1.435c.053 1.914.415 2.435.666.958.265-1.56.663-2 1.809-2h.489v4.5c0 4.899-.052 5.167-1.012 5.167-.239 0-.328.089-.29.291.081.422 3.872.536 4.031.121.072-.188-.043-.314-.401-.439-.794-.277-.828-.486-.828-5.212V83h.591c.826 0 1.352.567 1.492 1.604.148 1.101.199 1.229.495 1.229.213 0 .256-.289.256-1.75v-1.75H288.322l.047 1.709M305.5 82.64c0 .219.153.349.489.416.659.132.716.59.648 5.294-.057 3.967-.124 4.317-.836 4.317-.22 0-.307.094-.269.291.059.312 6.555.554 6.799.254.258-.316-.022-3.398-.304-3.344-.187.036-.309.304-.388.853-.202 1.415-.792 1.946-2.161 1.946-1.372 0-1.312.221-1.309-4.798.003-4.605.025-4.788.581-4.894 1.105-.209.26-.56-1.458-.606-1.669-.044-1.792-.025-1.792.271m20.333.015c0 .178.145.369.323.425.302.096.453.461 1.171 2.837.083.275.387 1.325.675 2.333 1.095 3.837 1.524 5.083 1.749 5.083.234 0 .315-.251 1.245-3.833.886-3.416.886-3.415 1.025-3.062.067.172.128.502.134.733.006.232.194.982.418 1.667.223.685.441 1.433.483 1.662.16.863.868 2.732 1.059 2.792.227.071.473-.706 1.789-5.664.949-3.575 1.237-4.352 1.673-4.519.141-.054.256-.254.256-.444 0-.485-2.709-.443-2.802.043-.04.212.053.292.34.292.481 0 .796.288.796.728 0 .591-1.554 5.952-1.686 5.819-.219-.22-1.843-6.2-1.732-6.379.057-.092.25-.168.428-.168.212 0 .323-.114.323-.333 0-.309-.111-.334-1.5-.334-1.532 0-2.058.338-1.241.796.275.153.721 1.235.734 1.778.01.46-1.208 4.76-1.349 4.76-.064 0-.193-.319-.287-.709-.2-.837-.323-1.283-1.015-3.694-.533-1.853-.551-2.264-.097-2.264.144 0 .255-.145.255-.333 0-.31-.111-.334-1.583-.334-1.454 0-1.584.027-1.584.322m-115.533.449c1.832 1.185 2.071 7.291.357 9.093-1.806 1.898-3.887-.435-3.893-4.364-.006-3.731 1.652-5.948 3.536-4.729m11.979.464c1.271 1.477.479 3.745-1.361 3.897l-.918.076v-1.843c0-2.505.111-2.766 1.123-2.652.568.064.885.207 1.156.522m-45.112 4.801c0 .072-.522.131-1.159.131h-1.159l.609-1.77.61-1.77.549 1.639c.302.901.55 1.697.55 1.77m104.666 0c0 .072-.518.131-1.153.131h-1.152l.6-1.78.6-1.779.553 1.648c.304.907.552 1.707.552 1.78m38.06-.327l.113.458h-2.315l.599-1.788.599-1.789.445 1.33c.245.732.496 1.537.559 1.789"
          fill="#ccb494"
        />
        <path
          d="M196.75 24.088c-.367.121-1.36.225-2.208.233l-1.542.012v.5c0 .426.064.5.428.5 1.584 0 1.572-.08 1.57 11.37-.003 11.101.055 10.571-1.208 10.951-.676.204-.79.3-.79.667v.429h6.667v-.451c0-.381-.088-.467-.57-.557a2.062 2.062 0 01-.958-.521l-.389-.414-.045-11.487c-.025-6.318-.1-11.479-.167-11.469a9.912 9.912 0 00-.788.237m7.667 0c-.367.121-1.361.225-2.209.233l-1.541.012v.5c0 .427.063.5.429.5 1.551 0 1.599.374 1.538 11.945l-.051 9.529-.389.414a2.062 2.062 0 01-.958.521c-.481.09-.569.176-.569.557v.451h6.666v-.429c0-.367-.114-.463-.789-.667-1.272-.383-1.205.305-1.208-12.446-.002-6.256-.059-11.367-.128-11.357a9.582 9.582 0 00-.791.237m-24.35.979c-.651.65-.796 2.006-.315 2.936.6 1.161 2.396 1.161 2.996 0 .778-1.503-.078-3.503-1.498-3.503-.479 0-.743.126-1.183.567m7.333 0c-1.659 1.658.106 4.667 2.109 3.595 1.581-.846.843-4.162-.926-4.162-.479 0-.743.126-1.183.567m182.509-.126c-1.327 1.431-.651 3.897 1.064 3.889 1.252-.006 1.861-.697 1.86-2.111-.002-1.848-1.829-2.96-2.924-1.778m-280.242-.03c-3.173.528-5.75 1.525-8.385 3.245-.711.464-1.356.844-1.434.844-.627 0-3.634 3.158-5.34 5.611-.5.718-1.074 1.509-1.275 1.757-1.159 1.428-3.588 7.048-4.402 10.185-.597 2.296-.557 2.073-1.113 6.28-.428 3.237-.429 12.455-.002 15.667.44 3.312.431 3.251.717 4.636 2.002 9.692 8.835 17.878 16.9 20.247 3.002.881 9.411 1.318 11.75.8a52.43 52.43 0 011.747-.348c1.556-.278 5.074-2.182 6.509-3.523 4.022-3.758 4.517-3.539 5.602 2.488.064.354.141.379 1.023.333l.953-.05.083-12.166c.092-13.334.059-12.915 1.086-13.723.49-.385 1.887-.861 2.528-.861.364 0 .386-.061.386-1.093v-1.094l-1.208.136c-1.48.165-16.303.156-17.75-.011L97 64.15v2.135l1.375.114c6.158.511 6.708 1.551 6.708 12.684 0 8.11.054 7.814-1.737 9.584-3.981 3.931-10.478 4.772-16.256 2.102-7.511-3.47-11.172-12.626-11.537-28.852-.291-12.947 2.008-22.826 6.795-29.202.359-.477.652-.938.652-1.025 0-.086.567-.687 1.26-1.334 7.458-6.965 20.436-3.116 24.369 7.227.602 1.584 2.197 9.031 2.204 10.292 0 .069.525.125 1.167.125h1.167V26h-1.927l-.264 1.829c-.568 3.938-1.289 4.491-3.476 2.668-5.98-4.988-11.338-6.666-17.833-5.586m155.75 1.068c-1.938.51-2.747 2.217-1.596 3.367 1.421 1.422 3.534-.273 2.592-2.079-.311-.597-.247-.669.477-.533 2.363.443 3.265 3.384 1.51 4.925-.838.736-1.936 1.25-5.346 2.505-5.432 1.998-6.804 3.615-5.901 6.953 1.005 3.718 7.364 2.737 6.52-1.005-.342-1.517-2.104-1.829-2.812-.498-.393.738-.245 1.872.313 2.393l.507.473-.591.163c-2.155.596-3.804-2.128-2.257-3.728.557-.576 2.54-1.635 3.876-2.071.773-.252 1.49.12 2.196 1.139 3.603 5.199-3.568 10.831-9.62 7.556-3.803-2.059-4.255-8.172-.741-10.036l.735-.391.946.392c1.302.54 1.858.363 1.858-.591v-.663l-1.41-.083-1.41-.084-.487-.788c-1.667-2.7.068-6.403 2.762-5.898 1.121.211 1.242.456.561 1.137-1.196 1.197-.602 2.948 1.004 2.961 2.599.02 2.055-3.94-.652-4.744-5.004-1.486-8.435 3.863-4.664 7.271l.647.584-.759.425c-2.788 1.56-3.592 2.951-3.592 6.215 0 10.201 16.225 10.901 16.876.728.139-2.168-.53-4.105-1.79-5.184l-.678-.58.528-.105c1.483-.297 3.559-1.525 4.345-2.57 2.741-3.646.137-8.63-3.947-7.556m20.271.111c-6.386 1.386-9.273 12.943-4.9 19.617 2.444 3.731 7.809 4.689 10.964 1.958.918-.795 1.17-.714 1.342.432.093.622.169.736.489.736h.379l.076-4.041c.085-4.491.092-4.532.893-4.797.459-.151.569-.274.569-.633v-.445h-6.833v.45c0 .392.082.465.625.555 1.874.31 2.041.642 2.041 4.05 0 2.895-.061 3.041-1.605 3.796-4.323 2.115-7.585-1.675-7.835-9.101-.294-8.729 3.047-13.549 7.816-11.274 1.986.948 2.793 2.342 3.369 5.815.093.558.157.625.596.625h.493v-7.522l-.459.053c-.396.046-.47.142-.547.719-.167 1.247-.32 1.308-1.233.485-1.746-1.572-3.688-2.032-6.24-1.478m-250.357-.036c-.046.049.015 1.35.136 2.892.246 3.112.359 15.613.15 16.596l-.132.625h2.276l.298-2.678C19.493 30.592 21.481 28.5 32.301 28.5h1.866l-.004 27.958c-.002 17.689-.064 28.387-.169 29.125-.536 3.759-1.913 4.827-6.869 5.33L26 91.027v2.056h24.167v-2.056l-1.125-.114c-5.006-.508-6.369-1.62-6.869-5.605-.113-.907-.173-10.91-.173-29.095V28.5h1.851c10.815 0 12.644 1.852 14.231 14.41.138 1.096.251 2.277.251 2.625v.632h2.084l.003-8.125c.002-5.203.076-8.811.206-10.03.112-1.048.18-1.928.152-1.956-.028-.028-2.933.032-6.456.133-6.287.18-34.127.087-37.405-.126-.825-.053-1.539-.057-1.586-.009m119.39 3.737l.029 3.375h.436c.472.001.647-.609.647-2.248 0-2.19 1.142-3.291 3.637-3.509l1.374-.12-.047 9.564c-.055 11.268.071 10.588-2.025 10.902-.694.104-.772.161-.772.556v.439h8.167v-.444c0-.392-.082-.457-.709-.561-2.034-.338-1.956.109-1.957-11.142l-.001-9.313 1.368.12c2.79.243 3.366.98 3.883 4.965.094.723.142.792.551.791h.448l.022-3.375.022-3.374h-15.102l.029 3.374m23.946 2.157c-.681.242-1.572 1.034-2.17 1.929l-.664.994V31.958l-.541.116c-1.338.285-2.534.394-3.378.307l-.914-.094v.494c0 .429.08.514.609.648 1.294.328 1.301.363 1.359 6.791.064 7.13.041 7.251-1.399 7.522-.56.105-.736.441-.441.841.075.103 1.523.167 3.747.167h3.625v-.451c0-.389-.085-.466-.625-.564-1.938-.351-2.042-.647-2.04-5.771.003-4.958.222-5.959 1.718-7.86.805-1.023 2.164-1.465 1.531-.498-1.05 1.602.328 3.593 1.952 2.822 2.425-1.151.185-5.386-2.369-4.48m54.691.054c-3.605.759-5.731 6.485-4.44 11.958 1.625 6.893 9.781 7.189 11.548.419 1.942-7.438-1.564-13.543-7.108-12.377m84.196-.005c-5.986 1.271-6.595 14.921-.755 16.911 1.123.382 3.26.338 4.201-.088 1.823-.826 3.752-4.059 2.632-4.414-.202-.064-.391-.047-.419.039-1.91 5.729-7.705 2.868-7.712-3.806-.002-1.59-.35-1.472 4.35-1.472H304l-.006-.625c-.043-4.688-2.66-7.347-6.44-6.545m15.363.143c-.798.382-1.573 1.171-2.154 2.193l-.426.75-.002-1.561c-.002-1.54-.007-1.559-.377-1.451-.889.261-2.445.408-3.332.315l-.959-.1v.505c0 .441.071.519.556.61.307.057.738.296.959.531l.401.428.043 6.112c.048 6.955.072 6.809-1.17 7.182-.675.204-.789.3-.789.667v.429h7.5v-.44c0-.376-.09-.456-.625-.555-2.063-.382-2.209-.756-2.209-5.667 0-4.882.449-6.697 2.027-8.203.974-.93 2.167-1.146 1.476-.268-.48.61-.472 2.077.014 2.529 1.226 1.143 2.871.194 2.878-1.659.007-1.977-2.001-3.214-3.811-2.347m11.786.047c-.715.354-1.595 1.292-2.092 2.23-.259.49-.264.472-.271-.979l-.007-1.48-.541.116c-1.375.293-2.614.407-3.417.315l-.875-.102v.523c0 .387.076.523.292.524 1.556.003 1.748.912 1.679 7.944-.061 6.223-.059 6.212-1.402 6.464-.481.09-.569.176-.569.557v.451h7.5v-.451c0-.389-.085-.466-.625-.564-2.008-.363-2.073-.562-2.008-6.121.061-5.097.139-5.49 1.426-7.197.961-1.275 2.43-1.897 1.717-.727-1.005 1.647.38 3.519 2.026 2.738 1.522-.722 1.232-3.446-.453-4.261-.88-.426-1.489-.421-2.38.02m9.175-.188c-1.799.381-3.418 1.741-3.611 3.032-.296 1.973 1.332 3.228 2.682 2.067.73-.628.695-2.255-.063-2.933l-.531-.474.404-.265c2.379-1.558 4.123-.4 4.214 2.798.071 2.514-.181 2.812-3.469 4.108-3.129 1.233-4.566 3.803-3.645 6.518.875 2.579 4.675 2.969 6.636.681.465-.542.67-.69.671-.483.006 1.773 2.429 2.573 4.159 1.375 1.129-.783.836-1.762-.331-1.106-1.253.704-1.231.813-1.327-6.531-.091-6.955-.074-6.835-1.11-7.819-.948-.899-3-1.324-4.679-.968m-167.545.197c-.229.097-1.185.177-2.125.178l-1.708.002v.46c0 .39.085.476.557.565.306.057.737.296.958.531l.402.428.113 5.778c.113 5.784.178 6.483.693 7.478 1.241 2.394 5.293 2.043 6.972-.604l.472-.744v1.469c0 1.444.006 1.467.375 1.36 1.022-.295 2.311-.427 3.25-.331l1.041.106v-.485c0-.433-.079-.506-.744-.684-1.356-.362-1.332-.212-1.389-8.513l-.05-7.226-.45.102c-1.416.319-2.354.413-3.223.322l-.977-.102v.505c0 .441.071.519.557.61 1.328.249 1.61 1.264 1.604 5.766-.009 6.047-1.091 8.666-3.58 8.666-1.784 0-1.821-.168-1.882-8.708-.039-5.381-.1-7.122-.25-7.114-.11.005-.386.089-.616.185m15.5-.001c-.229.096-1.148.174-2.041.175l-1.625.001v.452c0 .38.096.476.609.606 1.347.341 1.307.068 1.307 9.042v7.946l-.388.916c-.585 1.383-1.089 1.949-2.033 2.284-1.202.427-1.249 1.153-.064.99 1.839-.252 2.991-1.128 3.924-2.984 1.133-2.253 1.181-2.7 1.264-11.665.081-8.82.154-8.225-.953-7.763m7.25.001c-.275.092-1.231.169-2.125.171l-1.625.003v.482c0 .374.076.481.342.481 1.619 0 1.742.523 1.742 7.424 0 6.68.018 6.583-1.339 6.946-.634.17-.745.262-.745.623v.424h6.834v-.424c0-.361-.111-.453-.745-.623-1.377-.368-1.332-.094-1.39-8.404-.039-5.522-.1-7.296-.25-7.285-.109.008-.424.09-.699.182m90.584.064c-.544.127-1.375.176-2.042.122l-1.125-.092v.492c0 .428.08.513.609.647 1.291.327 1.295.349 1.405 6.958.117 7.034.25 7.646 1.847 8.46 1.757.897 4.442.139 5.597-1.579l.542-.806v1.372c0 1.343.008 1.369.375 1.263 1.022-.295 2.312-.427 3.25-.331l1.042.106v-.519c0-.384-.077-.52-.292-.52-1.588-.004-1.706-.619-1.707-8.875-.001-3.827-.058-6.958-.126-6.958-.069 0-.65.111-1.292.247-.75.159-1.539.211-2.208.144l-1.042-.104v.494c0 .429.08.514.609.648 1.251.317 1.301.522 1.357 5.507.074 6.558-.689 8.609-3.294 8.859-1.887.182-2.003-.334-2.004-8.92-.001-6.445-.02-6.874-.293-6.852-.16.013-.704.119-1.208.237m91.916-.068c-.275.09-1.231.167-2.125.171l-1.625.008v.481c0 .374.076.481.342.481 1.574 0 1.658.38 1.658 7.432v6.083l-.398.399c-.219.218-.669.448-1 .511-.511.095-.602.179-.602.552v.44h6.834v-.424c0-.361-.111-.453-.745-.623-1.377-.368-1.332-.093-1.387-8.404-.037-5.584-.096-7.296-.25-7.285-.111.008-.427.088-.702.178m-28.416 3.016v2.959h.489c.459 0 .497-.051.597-.792.426-3.156 1.51-4.208 4.335-4.208 1.922 0 1.925-.358-.029 3.498-.766 1.511-1.392 2.836-1.392 2.944 0 .107-.975 2.139-2.167 4.513-1.192 2.375-2.167 4.426-2.167 4.557 0 .201.826.238 5.355.238h5.355l-.104-1.334a47.283 47.283 0 01-.105-2.958L353.333 43h-.5c-.457 0-.5.048-.5.566 0 2.872-1.731 4.506-4.661 4.399l-1.326-.048.429-1c.235-.55 1.92-4.021 3.743-7.713s3.315-6.767 3.315-6.834c0-.066-2.4-.12-5.333-.12h-5.333v2.958m12.566-2.226c.055.402.1 1.733.1 2.958v2.227h.5c.453 0 .501-.052.502-.542.006-1.663.964-3.584 2.049-4.109.663-.321 3.949-.547 3.949-.272 0 .178-.727 1.691-4.026 8.379-1.911 3.873-3.474 7.098-3.474 7.167 0 .07 2.4.127 5.333.127H366V43h-.471c-.45 0-.481.05-.678 1.125-.361 1.965-1.023 3.023-2.258 3.609-.574.273-3.593.395-3.593.146 0-.153 2.757-5.897 5.432-11.321 1.138-2.304 2.068-4.217 2.068-4.25 0-.032-2.445-.059-5.433-.059h-5.434l.1.732m-139.632.437c2.587 1.973 2.757 11.531.249 14.038-2.143 2.143-4.399-.176-4.853-4.988-.618-6.549 1.759-11.22 4.604-9.05m83.367-.352c.85.439 1.699 2.588 1.699 4.301v.799h-5.546l.107-.914c.343-2.918 2.192-4.987 3.74-4.186M336.494 45.9c-1.693 2.358-4.32 1.608-4.32-1.233 0-1.608.878-2.681 3.243-3.964l1.5-.814.046 2.647.045 2.648-.514.716M224.499 62.98c-4.741 1.541-5.241 10.841-.689 12.815 1.16.503 3.031.381 3.936-.257.806-.568 1.087-.575 1.087-.028 0 .212.115.323.334.323.316 0 .333-.111.333-2.174 0-2.106.013-2.187.417-2.561.801-.742.604-.848-1.591-.857-1.931-.008-2.005.004-1.958.334.033.231.193.358.495.393 1.415.164 1.355 3.566-.074 4.199-3.139 1.388-5.363-4.176-3.688-9.222 1.092-3.287 4.903-3.049 5.571.348.301 1.532.828 1.52.828-.019 0-.582.049-1.526.109-2.098.113-1.088-.595-1.612-.746-.551-.066.468-.01.477-1.034-.16-.909-.565-2.411-.783-3.33-.485m106.128.019c-4.37 1.316-5.092 10.341-1.003 12.54 1.565.841 3.171.801 4.531-.115l.826-.555.106.482c.072.328.209.482.426.482.3 0 .32-.142.32-2.261 0-2.247-.002-2.262-.373-2.209-.313.045-.394.196-.499.934-.39 2.718-2.819 3.991-4.536 2.377-2.239-2.103-2.074-8.983.256-10.712 1.567-1.163 3.997.261 4.262 2.497.092.779.147.874.497.874.392 0 .393-.005.393-2.083 0-1.943-.021-2.083-.32-2.083-.22 0-.354.156-.429.497l-.109.498-.623-.5c-.967-.777-2.462-1.043-3.725-.663m-155.764.447c.029.154.272.338.539.41.753.201.759.251.762 5.602.003 5.488-.036 5.709-.997 5.709-.223 0-.334.111-.334.333 0 .324.111.333 4.084.333H183v-2c0-1.873-.021-2-.326-2-.246 0-.352.153-.432.625-.387 2.269-.737 2.625-2.58 2.625-1.872 0-1.745.406-1.745-5.566 0-5.517.025-5.684.853-5.684.286 0 .397-.093.397-.333 0-.316-.111-.333-2.179-.333-1.95 0-2.173.029-2.125.279M289.5 63.5c0 .24.111.333.396.333.76 0 .778.142.731 5.77l-.044 5.314-.541.159c-.351.103-.542.265-.542.458 0 .273.198.299 2.25.299 2.095 0 2.25-.021 2.25-.314 0-.228-.161-.345-.581-.424-.8-.15-.919-.473-.919-2.501v-1.761l.958-.001c1.443-.001 2.202-.274 2.963-1.064 1.755-1.821 1.413-5.259-.621-6.244-1.098-.531-6.3-.551-6.3-.024m12.167 0c0 .243.111.333.41.333.708 0 .756.357.756 5.619 0 5.318-.058 5.715-.842 5.715-.213 0-.324.114-.324.333 0 .324.111.333 4 .333h4v-2c0-2.085-.341-2.885-.587-1.375-.343 2.114-.883 2.625-2.772 2.625-1.848 0-1.725.4-1.725-5.566 0-5.517.025-5.684.854-5.684.285 0 .396-.093.396-.333 0-.316-.111-.333-2.083-.333-1.972 0-2.083.017-2.083.333m12.666 0c0 .218.111.333.322.333.82 0 .845.166.845 5.596 0 5.439-.048 5.738-.917 5.738-.139 0-.25.148-.25.333 0 .324.111.333 4 .333h4v-2c0-1.873-.02-2-.325-2-.247 0-.352.152-.431.625-.383 2.293-1.981 3.329-3.952 2.562l-.458-.178v-5.305c0-5.614.012-5.704.783-5.704.272 0 .383-.096.383-.333 0-.315-.111-.333-2-.333s-2 .018-2 .333m-19.529.751c1.826 1.536.843 5.696-1.39 5.881l-.914.076v-2.865c0-1.656.073-3.001.173-3.187.266-.499 1.491-.444 2.131.095m-105.592 2.243c-1.636.743-1.847 3.006-.281 3.006.864 0 1.231-1.123.643-1.963-.246-.351-.237-.38.177-.537 1.228-.467 1.916.154 1.916 1.731 0 1.295-.106 1.429-1.738 2.182-2.037.941-2.722 2.048-2.28 3.689.382 1.42 2.243 1.861 3.572.848.446-.34.612-.399.612-.218 0 .137.167.366.371.509.808.566 2.463.122 2.463-.662 0-.457-.177-.513-.662-.21-.538.336-.585.075-.672-3.674-.09-3.925-.14-4.147-1.052-4.703-.701-.428-2.125-.427-3.069.002m47.288-.13c-.321.093-.865.13-1.208.084-.774-.103-.967.597-.216.785.602.151.755.952.756 3.955.002 3.243-.069 3.638-.691 3.873-1.271.479-.597.772 1.776.772 2.094 0 2.25-.021 2.25-.314 0-.228-.162-.345-.585-.425-1.011-.19-1.121-.55-1.053-3.463.063-2.738.182-3.187 1.105-4.173.554-.592.725-.581.511.033-.435 1.246 1.262 2.131 1.827.953.856-1.786-1.38-3.076-2.825-1.63l-.647.647v-.647c0-.7-.05-.723-1-.45m10.75.027c-3.207 1.471-2.929 8.683.37 9.599 2.769.769 4.463-1.094 4.463-4.907 0-3.777-2.191-5.904-4.833-4.692m11.089-.029a3.424 3.424 0 01-1.125.102c-.479-.056-.547-.016-.547.319 0 .215.101.384.229.384.597 0 .686.48.771 4.181l.083 3.631.488.508c.856.894 2.323.888 3.349-.012l.58-.51v.621c0 .567.032.609.375.5.206-.065.843-.158 1.416-.205 1.027-.085 1.66-.714.719-.714-.549 0-.591-.289-.677-4.667-.081-4.133-.092-4.249-.417-4.197-.183.029-.839.066-1.458.083-1.046.029-1.125.057-1.125.406 0 .259.099.375.321.375.755 0 .846.349.846 3.267 0 3.486-.489 4.733-1.854 4.733-.885 0-.98-.485-.98-4.992 0-3.104-.047-4.005-.208-3.993-.115.008-.468.089-.786.18m12.661.002c-.321.093-.865.13-1.208.084-.572-.076-.625-.049-.625.318 0 .281.093.401.313.401.722 0 .767.295.821 5.392.057 5.343.037 5.551-.556 5.776-1.142.434-.489.748 1.588.764 1.847.014 2-.009 2-.296 0-.213-.159-.343-.506-.413-.74-.148-.994-.626-.994-1.87 0-1.047.008-1.065.321-.782 1.323 1.198 3.848-.054 4.582-2.271 1.547-4.671-1.51-9.356-4.325-6.628l-.578.56v-.616c0-.339-.056-.61-.125-.601a8.98 8.98 0 00-.708.182m-73.5.359c0 .169.153.431.34.584.313.254 1.613 3.88 2.683 7.485.409 1.376.823 1.623 1.118.666l.959-3.125c.931-3.035.977-3.114 1.21-2.057.672 3.054 2.143 6.401 2.43 5.528.04-.121.604-2.015 1.254-4.209 1.189-4.013 1.355-4.428 1.776-4.428.127 0 .23-.168.23-.375 0-.36-.059-.375-1.417-.375s-1.416.015-1.416.375c0 .253.099.375.307.375.884 0 .908.438.173 3.055-.731 2.596-.865 2.811-1.142 1.82-.732-2.623-1.82-5.631-2.053-5.677-.205-.04-.419.445-.952 2.166a1719.89 1719.89 0 01-.948 3.052c-.404 1.296-.453 1.245-1.202-1.252-.798-2.659-.816-3.056-.142-3.134.344-.039.459-.143.459-.416 0-.352-.06-.364-1.833-.364-1.669 0-1.834.027-1.834.306m51.764.398c1.244 1.245 1.458 5.922.346 7.577-1.463 2.178-3.269-1.353-2.636-5.152.352-2.115 1.444-3.271 2.29-2.425m25.018.129c1.32.924 1.35 6.193.044 7.591-.62.664-1.345.665-2.005.005l-.488-.487.004-2.638c.004-3.018.213-3.785 1.195-4.384.661-.402.788-.411 1.25-.087m-82.941 6.907c-.879 1.234-2.23.796-2.23-.723 0-.923.216-1.19 1.556-1.921l.916-.5.049 1.333c.041 1.124-.005 1.408-.291 1.811m87.418-.287c-.591.844-.122 2.297.741 2.297.53 0 .265.856-.444 1.437-.241.198-.136.729.145.729.775 0 1.734-1.986 1.587-3.287-.162-1.441-1.358-2.134-2.029-1.176"
          fill="#0c1c44"
        />
      </g>
    </svg>
  );
}

export default SvgComponent;
```

Rendering Logic:

```
import Logo from '../../Assets/Logo'
const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <div className='nav-o'>
      <div className='nav-i'>
        <div className='nav-fl-ctr'>
          <Logo />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default NavBar
```

attached is a code sandbox so you can see what I mean and use it for debugging.  I have added a border around the svg to show you what I mean about there being extra space around the path of the svg.  https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-edison-2x5t3?file=/src/App.js:0-22963

Comment: please try this instead: `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="400" viewBox="15 23.5 360 71" style="border: 1px solid red;">`

Comment: this works and can be accepted as the answer would you like to submit this so I can give you the points